# SQL show row count in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got this little code with name telephone and mail data. I need to show count of people registered with php how can I do that? What should I add to the code?

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='1106428';
$password='';
$dbname = "1106428";
try {
    $adsoyad = $_POST['adsoyad'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    /* set the PDO error mode to exception */
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO ufc3 (adsoyad,mail,tel)
    VALUES ('$adsoyad', '$mail','$tel')";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {

        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Instead of substituting text for the input values. you should use parameters (to avoid sql injection.)

Comment: This is too broad. We have no idea what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use php form to add user, you car just make a Count with sql and you get the number but if you have 2 way or more to add user you can add a new variable to you database like `addedfrom` and you set it to `php`.